# How to increase the size of a custom dropdown item width in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am using ckeditor.And i have created a custom dropdown in the toolbar.
I am able to set the width of the dropdown but the items are truncated inside it.
Is there any way to increase the item width ?

Comment: How do you do the width setting? `.cke_combopanel` width?

Comment: in the editor.css there is a class cke_combo_text
I have set the width there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the same width you applied to cke_combo_text to cke_combopanel, that should do the trick.

Comment: Well, maybe not the same width but play around with values until you find a good one that works for you. The setting is also in editor.css

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using ckeditor's strinsert plugin for dropdown list then add this to the editor.css in skin folder

```
.cke_combo__strinsert, .cke_combo_button, .cke_combo_label {
    width: 150px !important;
}
.cke_combo_text, .cke_combo_open {
    width: 115px !important;
}
```